# I have over 200 of these analytics in my phone settings can anyone tell me what they mean please?

Tags: iphone, analytics

I hope someone here can help me, I have s that my partner of the last three years may be tracking my phone and laptop... I found over 200 analytics in my settings on my iphone. I am new to all this and he denies any computer knowledge but I am guessing these analytics may be stopping me accessing certain apps on my phone. I will include a couple of the analytics so you may be able to tell me exactly what they do and can I remove them?

I have been trying to work out how to show you the code but I cannot for the life of me work it out.. can anyone tell me how to share these analytics??

Tracey

Comment: Your name is very fitting.

Comment: But on a more serious note; I think you should talk to your partner, or ask questions about that interaction here: https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/